# Queue different commands in cocos2d (CCSequene)

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, queue

I'm trying to make a label fade out from the screen, then after that if finished remove it from the view. How do I queue it so that the view waits for the label to be fully faded before it removes it?

```
id sequence = [CCSequence actions:[splashLabel runAction:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5]], [self removeChild:splashLabel cleanup:YES], nil];
[self runAction:sequence];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    id fade=[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.0f];





    id delay=[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2];




    id seqq=[CCSequence actions:fade,delay,nil];


    [splashLabel runAction:seqq];



        id stopAni=[splashLabel stopAllActions];

    id remove=[self removeChild:splashLabel cleanup:YES];








    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:stopAni,remove,nil]];
```